# How do I copy Lookup Column to another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I would like to calculate a Lookup Field. I am trying to figure out how to copy the Lookout Field using workflow. I did find some tips but they were using 2010 workflow which I keep getting Access Denied when I tried to save or publish. Is it possible to do it using 2013 workflow platform?

I have a column with numer on one list. And the second list supposts to loopup this number and use it to calculate expiration date from start date.

I tried using Update List but it seems to go into loop.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint is your environment: on-prem 2013 - 2013, 2016, or 2019. Or SharePoint Online?

Comment: By the way, welcome to the SharePoint community on StackExchange.  I have found this forum immensely useful for answering technical questions over the years and I hope you do too.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome :) It's SharePoint Online included in Office 365. I am trying to make a traning management for my department - courses, reminder to take class, calculate expiration date etc. I don't have the admin access, only owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:  “to copy a look up column to another column” it depends on what you are trying to copy.   A lookup column, under the hood it is a URL to another ***list item*** in another list or library.

Basically what the workflow value you are looking for is the ID value in the **source list** that corresponds to the value you are trying to match in the target list.  Then in the workflow you could concatenate a URL that looks like the following with your data:

**https://*your tenant*.sharepoint.com/sites/*your site collection name*/*your site name - if any*/Lists/*Source List Name*/Item/displayifs.aspx?ID= Followed by the numeric ID value of the item you want to link to.**

It sounds like you are using SharePoint Designer as your authoring tool for workflows.
If so, and If your site has multiple triggers for user actions, I strongly suggest using Microsoft Flow, instead of the legacy SP Designer Workflows, they are far more reliable and have many more connectors to additional services.

Comment: Please let me explain a little bit about my project. I have a list call "Course Name" which contain courses info items - "course name" , "validation days" (ex. 180 day to retrain). And I have another list called "Open Course" in here user can add a course and pick the name of the course from the first list (lookup from first" and choose the "start date" of the course. Also in this list, a calumn called "Valid Until" will take the start date (manually select) and + validation days (ex. 180 days, additiinal field from lookup) = the day the needs to retrain.